# Will Windows recovery partition become useless when dual install with Ubuntu?

Tags: dual-boot, windows-7

My laptop is Lenovo with Windows 7.

I was wondering if I dual install Ubuntu, the Windows recovery partition will be of no use any more? I am confused because I heard of this and don't understand why.

Thanks and regards!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trying to restore your Win7 system will destroy an Ubuntu installation. Suggestion: When you installed and configured WinXP/7 system you always peform a backup of WinXP/7 partition by mean of backup software (for Windows). So you will be able to restore corrupted Windows system later. It does not harm your Ubuntu installation, however it may overwrite Grub settings. In such case, you may restore your Grub by use of software like SuperGrub. It will reconstruct your Grub functionality.

Comment: Just booting from the ubutnu dvd and selecting rescue mode and letting it chroot to the right spot for you, then doing a grub-install is sufficient.  No outside tools are necessary to reinstall grub.

Answer (score 2):

If you can set to boot from it, it can still be useful.  It will, however, destroy your ubuntu partition if you choose to restore.

the destruction of the ubuntu partition is based off of this "recovery" partition just restoring an image instead of doing a REAL install.  while it may not be true in absolutely every case, it almost always is true.  i have personally used a recovery partition to restore the OS after installing multiple linux and bsd derivatives.  i can't speak to the lenovo recovery specifically.